# Laravel 5.8 routes sometimes called multiple times

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm not sure why, but Laravel routes are sometimes requested multiple times in a row. It only happens on the web.php route (not api.php). I've tried to disable all web global middlewares and I get the same result.

Heres what I'm using in web.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return "ok";
});
```

Telescope will sometimes show multiple requests were made to fetch "/", sometimes not. I can't figure out when it happens as it's seemingly random. It happens both with Safari 12 and Chrome 77. This happens on all my defined routes, not just this basic test one.

This is happening both on my local environment and my production environment, usually 1-10 seconds after the initial request. Has anyone run into something similar?

Comment: have you checked the methods on those calls, maybe it's an `OPTION` preflight request from browser.

Comment: Issues like this are usually caused by middlewares or packages.  Does this happen only to base URL ?

Comment: @EmekaMbah, no, it happens on all routes defined by the web.php file.

Comment: @N69S I think I'm not seeing this issue when running requests through Postman - how can I log what requests come from the browser in Laravel? `$request` returns empty.

Comment: @N69S never-mind the problem also exists through Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, and it was very strange indeed.

It was caused by a `style="background: url('')"`, where the `url` was empty, so the browser assumed it was referencing the same page and caused it to load again, sometimes multiple times until the browser decided to stop the reload/load madness.

It happened on all the pages as it was in the layout blade template.